# Running multiple browsers on same machine using selenium grid and testng

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, selenium-grid

Here is the code:  I want to open multiple browsers on same machine where the eclipse resides it self. Problem I am facing is how to declare the setup method or testng.xml so that I can run multiple browsers. my Test contain only one @Test method.

```
@BeforeMethod   
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
   URL url=new URL("http://localhost:4445/wd/hub");
   DesiredCapabilities capability=new DesiredCapabilities();
   capability.setBrowserName("internet explorer");
   driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url,capability);
   baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.in/";
   //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testF() throws Exception {
   driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
}
```

Comment: In the above code its working with IE but I want a simultaneous execution of Firefox browser also that should execute the same @Test method

Answer (score 0):

To get multiple browsers out of that you need to add a DataProvider method that returns a 2 dimensional Object array.  If your array is 2-wide by 5 long, then your @Test annotated method needs to consume those 2 arguments  5 separate times and so you need to also edit your method signature.   What I do is have the DataProvider return a `Map<String,String>` with testName and browser type AND another object that is a browser wrapper; I usually call it `WDHelper`.   The browser wrapper is careful not to instantiate the browser until the moment that .navigateTo(url) is called.   I use Builder design pattern but you can also do it something like:

```
@Test
public void testF( Map<String,String> params, WDHelper wdhelper ) {
    try {
        wdhelper.loadDriver( params.get("browser") );
    catch ( WebDriverException e ) {
        //do nothing yet 
    }
    wdhelper.navigateTo( params.get("url") );
}
```

Keep in mind that TestNG forks threads by class (usually) and so you need 2 or more test classes, each fed by the dataprovider  in order to trigger TestNG to fork another instance of the browser locally.  This is usually configured in the testng.xml file as a parameter called `parallel="classes"` .

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you can try

```
@Parameters({"browser"})
@BeforeMethod
public void setUp(String browser) throws MalformedURLException {
   URL url=new URL("http://localhost:4445/wd/hub");
   DesiredCapabilities capability=new DesiredCapabilities();
   capability.setBrowserName(browser);
   driver=new RemoteWebDriver(url,capability);
   baseUrl = "http://www.google.co.in/";
}
```

In your testng xml, create two tests and set parallel = tests

```
<suite name="My Suite1" parallel="tests" thread-count="5" >
    <test verbose="2" name="Default1 test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
         <classes>
            <class name="com.nv.demo.testngtests.ParamsTest"/>

          </classes>
      </test>
      <test verbose="2" name="Default2 test">
        <parameter name="browser" value="internet explorer"></parameter>
         <classes>
            <class name="com.nv.demo.testngtests.ParamsTest"/>

          </classes>
      </test>
 </suite>
```